# Pearson Correlation for batches of labels and predictions (Keras)

Tags: correlation, neural-networks, python, metric, keras

I want to implement a custom metric (pearson correlation) as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) in Keras. I get a batch (32) of predictions and labels. I use a neural network to predict 10 values. So my input is
32x10 predictions and 32x10 labels.

I would like to know how I get a single correlation value for batches of predictions/labels. Should I  calculate the correlation for each prediction/label sample in the batch individually and then take the mean over the 32 samples or should I treat the batch as a "population" and use the covariance between prediction and label and divide it by the standard deviations?

Comment: Came across this while looking for how to use Pearson's Correlation Coefficient in Keras. Might be of use if you're still interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619869/how-to-specify-the-correlation-coefficient-as-the-loss-function-in-keras